# How to implement multiple custom realms with RPX?

Tags: openid, rpx

Right now I have a free [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) account for integrating Open ID into my web site.  I understand that to get a custom realm with RPX (e.g. signon.example.com versus example.rpxnow.com) I need to sign up for the premium service level.

Before I can make a decision, I need to know some details on how custom realms are managed with RPX.  I have a couple specific questions which I haven't been able to find answers to in the RPX docs:

### How to implement multi-tenant scenario?

I have a multi-tenant web site, where each customer has a custom URL rooted off the main URL, e.g.:

- http://bob.example.com
- http://alice.example.com
- ... etc.

Each customer will be allowed to have their own set of Open ID users.  In RPX will I be able to have a realm for each customer URL?  I'm hoping there's a way to have a wildcard realm to cover all customers using the above URL scheme.

### How to provision custom realms?

What is the actual procedure to go about provisioning each custom realm URL to use with RPX?  Do I need update my DNS records for each customer URL to point to the RPX servers?

Answer (score 1):

The custom realm for RPX can be configured to use a single subdomain (signin.example.com) that then can call back to the individual websites, or you can configure a wildcard realm (*.example.com) and have the same RPX application work for all trust roots.  There are small pros & cons to each.

To turnup a custom realm you have to add a dns CNAME to point a name on the RPX side.  JanRain will handle the rest of the process, and when it is turned up you will have access to the dashboard & api key just like the free version you are using (but with more features ;))

larry-